# Parent process <- child processes UNIdirectional communication in "real-world" Haskell?

Tags: haskell, process, architecture, functional-programming

**Goal**:

1. There is an `IShell` which is nothing but an ordinary console able
   to    consume somewhat command like `do param1=value1 --option`. 
          `IShell` should orchestrate whole execution. It **does not** run    commands, the only thing it does is starts appropriate
   process.
2. **Any** process started from the running `IShell` instance should be able to report back to it what's happening inside. So,
   say, `IShell`    has started process `A` to do something
   complicated; process `A`    should be able to report both progress
   and result back to parent    `IShell`. In practice, it means, that
   there should be a mechanism how    to, for example, print message
   from process `A` to appropriate    `IShell`.
3. Finally, code should work both with Windows and Linux.

---

I really like Haskell and I'd like to promote "real-world" Haskell usage. But I don't know existing libraries well, I haven't done yet any "real-world" Haskell app.

Thus, questions:

How can I establish `IShell <- it's processes` communication? Is there a single library able to handle both Windows-specific and Linux-specific stuff?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Dynamic (at runtime) *dll/package substitution? preferably in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808147/dynamic-at-runtime-dll-package-substitution-preferably-in-haskell)?

Comment: @mpetruska nope, but both definitely related.

Comment: Is there a reason that stdout is not a suitable way for the child to send messages to the parent ishell?

Comment: @DanRobertson, well, the problem is that I am not quite familiar with stdin/stdout things. I knew it exists before, but never tried it out yet. However, seems to be perfectly valid candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [process](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.3.0/docs/System-Process.html) package supports Linux and Windows and provides mechanisms for communicating with children processes via their stdin, stdout, stderr, and exit code.

The [network](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.3.3/docs/Network-Socket.html) package supports Linux and Windows and provides mechanisms for communicating with children processes via socket.